# How to unit test a class with private constructor?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have a class Foo. I only want to allow Bar to create it, so I make its constructor private and make Bar its friend. But now how can I unit test Foo's public methods (e.g., getValue)? I do not have a way to create its instance in the unit test file.

```
class Foo final
{
public:
    int getValue();
private:
    friend class Bar;
    Foo(int value);
};

class Bar
{
protected:
    Foo createFoo(int value);
};
```

Comment: Maybe you need to revise your definition of "unit" a bit. Point is, that since your class can only be created via a factory, it's constructor isn't part of the interface. So, the two classes form a unit together rather than being units individually.

Comment: If you're using gcc or clang, you can compile your unit test with `-fno-access-control`, that will allow you to access private members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways.

The first is for the unit test to make use of `Bar` to instantiate `Foo`, and then do your tests on public members of `Foo`.     This means your unit test exercises the working of `Bar` and `Foo` in combination which is appropriate given that (presumably) your intent in making `Foo`s constructor private and `Bar` a friend is to prevent `Foo` being used separately.     Depending on how `Bar` is defined, you may need separate unit tests to exercise `Bar` in isolation (i.e. independently of `Foo`).

The second option is to declare another class as a `friend`, and then use that class to implement tests on `Foo` independently of `Bar`.

Personally, I would prefer the first option.   With the second option, there is a risk that the working of `Bar` gets out of sync with the working of `Foo`s unit test (or vice versa) - which means the second option would introduce the possibility of passing the unit test, and then releasing your program with a faulty interaction of `Bar` with `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an extra friend class for Unit testing

```
class Foo final
{
public:
    int getValue();
private:
    friend class Bar;
    friend class UnitTests; // Here
    Foo(int value);
};

class UnitTests {
public:
     bool constructor_ok() { Foo test_instance(42); ... }
};
```